# CORS on Image Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-canvas, cors

I have a server serves images, and I need to be able to manipulate the image in HTML5 canvas. I added CORS headers to the image server, and reference the image in the HTML using  tags. However, the image server won't return CORS headers when the client fetches the image in the  tag, unless I hit Ctrl-F5 on the browser. I added crossorigin=anonymous to the  tag, but still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are u using asp.net or what?

Comment: No, pure HTML5/Javascript. The image server is currently AWS S3, but I have also tried tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I feel your pain coz I have gone through the same problem. Can you see [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)

and follow the instruction because i solve the problem using the method described here. Especially using following code

```
// make sure the load event fires for cached images too
if ( img.complete || img.complete === undefined ) {
    img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
    img.src = src;
}
```

Comment: Probably a caching issue. I have images shows in page 1 first, and then when user clicks the images, it takes them to page 2 for editing. I only have crossorigin="anonymous" set in <img> in page 2. After adding crossorigin="anonymous" in page 1, it seems have fixed my issue.